# Count distinct values in an array - C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to teach myself (re-learn) C++ and doing problems from books and tests online to get some practice. I came across this problem which has left me a little confused. How would I best go about it?

I have to write a function

```
class Solution { public int distinct (int [] A); }
```

that returns the number of distinct values in the array  A.
I can assume that the array range is 0 to 100,000. And that the elements are all integers which are + or - 1,000,000.
Any ideas? I was thinking of looping through and counting up for each value but that's probably really inefficient right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have to write it in C++? That line you posted isn't valid C++. Looks like either C# or Java.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It is in Java. I should have made that clear (sleep deprived brain!). The question is still the same though, I want to do it in C++. How do I go about it?

Comment: I think your proposed solution makes sense. If you are just looping through some numbers it really is not going to take long. I assume you are going to just use a counter and increment it each time you encounter the number right?

Comment: The fastest way is to use www.google.com with instant searching, with the appropriate words which will lead you to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136279/count-the-number-of-distinct-absolute-values-among-the-elements-of-the-array

Answer (score 6):

**Edit** Updated: included a space-optimized algorithm as well just for fun

You can use a std::set to contain the unique values. Just copy the array elements into a set (anyway you like), and count the number of unique elements from the set afterwards.

Here is a rather succinct bit of code that doesn't require you to even specify the size of the array (though, normally in c++ you'd be using a `std::vector` anyway):

**See it live on http://ideone.com/rpWGS** (which contains test data and output)

```
#include <set>

class Solution 
{ 
   public: 

     // using std::set (max O(n) additional storage)
     template<size_t N>
         static size_t distinct (int (&a)[N])
     {
         return std::set<int>(a, a+N).size();
     }

     // using std::unique (inplace mutation; no additional storage)
     template<size_t N> 
         static size_t distinct_optim(int (&a)[N])
     {
         std::sort(a, a+N);
         int* newend = std::unique(a, a+N);
         return newend - a; 
     }

};
```

Comment: This doesn't look like an explanatory and easy answer for such question of a beginner, IMHO.

Comment: @KirilKirov: I clarified the answer a bit now, and there is a live demo here http://ideone.com/rpWGS

Comment: There's probaby a school of thought that this won't teach _much_ C++ programming :-) However, it's still a good answer since part of learning a language is knowing what it provides as part of the baseline, so you don't have to re-implement it.

Comment: I didn't look very hard, but does the test data on IdeOne have duplicates? If not, you might want to add some, to show it works even then.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: yes it does. The output explicit shows that by printing `136 DEBUG: size of array: 158 elements`, so: 22 were duplicates <grin/>

Comment: Oh ok, didn't see at stderr down there.

Comment: `O( n log n )` runtime and duplicate the space requirements in the worst case... simple, but probably not the best algorithmic approach

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: what's your suggested improvement? In place sort and eliminate adjacent duplicates? Added it in a  jiffy :)

Answer (score 6):

Your solution is reasonably efficient (in fact, about as efficient as possible, in terms of time complexity), but in space -- to count the values, you need an array sized to the range of the possible values, so to count the instances in your array of 100,000 items you need an auxiliary array of ~2,000,000 items (covering the range from -1,000,000 to 1,000,000).

You have a couple of ways to avoid/reduce that. One is to just store one bit for each possible input, and set the bit when you see that input. This has the same basic *complexity*, but reduces the space for the count to the minimum necessary (i.e., you don't really care how many times any input has occurred, only whether it occurred or not). In C++, the obvious way to do this would be `std::vector<bool>`. While often maligned, in this case, `vector<bool>` does exactly what you're looking for.

Another possibility would be to use a sparse mapping from the input numbers to the count/bit. Especially when your range is much larger than the number of inputs, this could save quite a bit of space (the space taken will be proportional to the number of inputs, not the range). In C++, the obvious way to do this would be `std::set<int>`. To maintain the same expected complexity (O(N) instead of O(N log N), you'd want to use an `unordered_set` instead.

Another possibility is to sort the inputs, then eliminate duplicates. This generally keeps auxiliary storage to a minimum, but generally requires slightly longer to execute (O(N log N) instead of O(N)). For this, you'd probably use `std::vector`, `std::sort`, and `std::unique`.

Comment: Isn't `vector<bool>` deprecated?

Comment: Also you could use `unordered_map`, as yet another option.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: At least AFAIK, no, it's not officially deprecated. I believe the wording has been changed in C++11, to just make bit-wise storage suggested instead of required though.

Comment: Vector-bool is maligned because it doesn't act like a proper vector in all cases, none of which matter for setting and testing specific elements of it. And being deprecated just means it may not be in the next standard (C++20 at the earliest) and may not work in compilers that decide to pedantically enforce the rule with no possibility of relaxing for backwards compatibility. No, I think we're quite safe with vector-bool for a while yet :-)

Comment: I implemented the 'inplace sort, then unique' version now too in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Sort the array A.
Then go through the sorted array and count the number of times the difference between two consecutive numbers is non zero. 
Make sure you take care of the edges of the array and cases where the array is of size 1.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options:

1) sort the vector using quick sort or merge sort, and then iterate over the sorted vector, counting up each time you encounter a value different from current value.

2) set up a `std::vector<bool>` of size 1,000,000 and put in `true` values as you iterate over your array. afterwards you count the number of `true` values. I say `vector<bool>` because it's optimized for efficient storage, i.e. it probably stores 8 bools in a byte.

Comment: `vector<bool>` is deprecated.

Comment: Apparently, since a while ago, but I wasn't aware of it until Seth pointed it out: [link](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=98)

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of distinct values in an array, I can see two possibilities.

The first is to sort them and then count the number of transitions (adding one). For example, the folloing list:

```
1 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 5
       ^   ^ ^   ^
```

has four transitions, hence five distint values.

The other possibility is to set up an array of "booleans" indicating whether a number had been seen before, pseudocode such as (in your case):

```
def countDistinct (array):
    def notSeenYet[-1,000,000..1,000,000] as all true
    count = 0
    for each value in array:
        if notSeenYet[value]:
            notSeenYet[value] = false
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

The first requires a sort which would be at best O(n log n) time complexity. This is unlikely to be a serious problem for 100,000 elements but you may not want the array modified in any way (which would require a copy, O(n) space complexity).

The second is O(n) time complexity and constant storage for your case. Two million boolean values *may* be of concern, depending on your environment but, if it's available, that would be better, assuming that time is your main concern (and it usually is).