# Number of objects of each specific type in std::list

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary

**How can I count the number of objects of a specific type in an collection (specifically, a list), in a general automatic manner which doesn't require me to identify the specific types of objects in advance?**

I have a class, `Card`, which is subclassed several times into `hearts`, `diamonds`, `spades` and `clubs`. Players have a `std::list<Card *> hand`. I want to count the number of each type of card currently in each players hand.

I can't [count instances of specific object types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097679/simplest-way-to-count-instances-of-an-object), because I'm initialising a `deck` containing lots of cards, and I only want to count the ones in the players hand.

I could do a set of if statements:

```
if ( strcmp( (*it)->cardType,"hearts")==0) {
...
} else if ( strcmp( (*it)->cardType,"diamonds")==0) {
...
} else if ...
```

but this will get tedious if I wish to add a new card type (I'm aiming to simulate the play of games with around 200 types of cards).

Inserting each element into a set gives me the [number of distinct elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136279/count-the-number-of-distinct-absolute-values-among-the-elements-of-the-array), but I want to know the number of each of those distinct elements ("4 hearts, 3 clubs etc", not "4 different suits").

Is there an already-implemented method to do this in the C++ STL?

Comment: Why use `list<Card*>` when you can use `list<Card>` or `list<shared_ptr<Card>>` if a pointer is must?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::map` as:

```
std::map<std::string, int>  counts;

for(auto const & item : hand)
    ++counts[item->cardType]; //because item is Card*
```

Here the overloaded operator `[]` for `std::map` returns a reference to the value for the associated key (if the key exists). The value is incremented using the returned reference. If the key doesn't exist, a new entry is created using the key, and a default-initialized value which is zero in this case, and then it returns the reference.

Once you're done with the counting, you can print them as:

```
for(auto const & c : counts)
     std::cout << c.first << " appears  " << c.second << " times.\n";
```

which will print something like this:

```
hearts appears 3 times.
diamonds appears 7 times.
spades appears 4 times.
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: btw, you want to loop over `hand` and use `++counts[item->cardType()]`

Comment: @aschepler: Nice choice if the order is irrelevant.